# Characterizing a functional that takes convolution to addition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $H:L^2[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy
$$H(f*g)=H(f)+H(g).$$
**Question**:Is there a characterization of all such functionals $H$?

**Related questions**:Can it be extended to measures? If so, is it enough to know that the equation holds for discrete measures?

PS: I earlier asked [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144593/characterization-of-the-laplace-transform)

Comment: I gather here that by "functional" you don't mean "linear", right? Do you imply on the other hand a continuity assumption?

Comment: referring to this earlier related question you mention, isn't $H(f)$ just the logarithm of the (generalized) Fourier transform of $f$?

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier I struggled a bit trying to decide what assumptions to add, but since the question asks for a characterization, what extra assumptions are needed---if any---is part of the question. I hope this doesn't make the question too vague; I would accept an answer that assumes linearity. Do you think I should reword the question?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker The Fourier transform has an image on complex-valued functions, so I believe the two are somewhat different. Besides, regarding the previous question, I'm still not sure if the Fourier transform is uniquely defined by that property.

Comment: Alesker, Artstein, Faifman and Milman studied closely related questions in
 http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.ijm/1336049986
(see in particular their theorem 4). This applies to your map after exponentiation; they note that the real version of their result is in
S. Alesker, S. Artstein-Avidan and V. Milman, A characterization of the Fourier
transform and related topics, Linear and complex analysis, Amer. Math. Soc.
Transl. Ser. 2, vol. 226, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2009, pp. 11–26.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation

Comment: @oferzeitouni Thanks! That seems to be very much in line with what I'm looking for.